# SQL One Query with Three Conditions

Tags: sql

I have query with 3 conditions which I cannot get right output.

*my logic is :*

**1st condition If Status is 'Approved', and ProcStatus is 'NULL' and MDStatus is 'NULL' then RESULT out.**

**2nd condition If Status is 'Approved', and ProcStatus is 'Approved' and MDStatus is 'NULL' RESULT out.**

**3rd condition If Status is 'Approved', and ProcStatus is 'Approved' and MDStatus is 'Approved' RESULT out**.

I have one query for above three conditions but when I run this some 'Rejected' result is out.
Below is my query.

```
SELECT PRReqID,
Status,
ProcStatus,
MDStatus
FROM tbl WHERE (Status! ='Reject' and  (Procstatus!='Reject' or MDstatus!='Reject'))
```

Comment: Could you clarify `'Reject'` vs `'Rejected'`? Your query is all `'Reject'` but you said you got a result of `'Rejected'`.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the current (unwanted) result, and also the wanted result - all as formatted text, not images. [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way of doing this

```
SELECT PRReqID,
       Status,
       ProcStatus,
       MDStatus
   FROM tbl 
  WHERE Status ='Approved' 
    AND ISNULL(Procstatus,'Approved')='Approved'
    AND ISNULL(MDstatus,'Approved')='Approved
```

If you are looking for better readability i would use UNION ALL statments as follows

```
    SELECT PRReqID,
           Status,
           ProcStatus,
           MDStatus
       FROM tbl 
      WHERE Status ='Approved' 
        AND Procstatus IS NULL
        AND MDstatus IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PRReqID,
           Status,
           ProcStatus,
           MDStatus
       FROM tbl 
      WHERE Status ='Approved' 
        AND Procstatus='Approved'
        AND MDstatus IS NULL
 UNION ALL
    SELECT PRReqID,
           Status,
           ProcStatus,
           MDStatus
       FROM tbl 
      WHERE Status ='Approved' 
        AND Procstatus='Approved'
        AND MDstatus ='Approved'
```

Comment: Exactly what i want.
Thanks ^_^

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph . . . I hope the `UNION ALL` is intended as a joke.

Comment: I mentioned on readability in the comment. Also indexes on Procstatus would be prevented with a function on the column like ISNULL

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly: what about a CASE Statement ?

```
where 
 (case 
   when Status = 'Reject' then 1
   when Procstatus = 'Reject' then 1
   when MDstatus = 'Reject' then 1
   else 0
  END)     
 = 0
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.